# How can I detach an entity in JPA 1.0?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-5

[The Java EE 5 version of Entity Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) doesn't have a `detach` method, but I need this exact functionality.  Is there a way to detach an entity in JPA 1.0, or is this functionality impossible to do?

Comment: `clear()` if you can handle all of them being detached.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm worried that will have side effects that will take a long time to discover.  Is there no way to detach a single one in JPA1.0?

Comment: If your object is in session, then it is attached. Once session closes you object will be detached. Are you looking for detach object from live session?

Comment: @CHowdappaM Yes, I'm in a live session, but that is good information to know.

Comment: @CHowdappaM: Let me ask another question that would alleviate my concerns: I've got an entity which has a List of other entities.  I want to modify that list but I don't want to persist any modifications back to the database.  If I get the List then wrap it in a `new ArrayList(list);` and then use the result, will that protect me?

Comment: @tieTYT, NO. Can you try by cloning.

Comment: Unfortunately 1.0 is only able to detach all as Sotirios said.  They introduced single detachments in 2.0

Comment: You could serialize/marshal the object and use the deserialized/unmarshalled version - it will be detached.

Comment: I use Dozer mapper to quickly copy the data from an entity into a 'DTO Class' so that I don't have to worry about unintended side effects.